# Bootstrap 3 load section from remote URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Let me start off by saying my bootstrap modal load remote works fine. My particular problem is that it loads the whole remote URL as the HTML result, and I just need some specific sections from that HTML. For instance, lets say my remote URL is like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {head content goes here}
</head>
<body>
    {some content here}
    <div id="myContent1">{more content here}</div>
    ...
    <div id="myContent2">{even more content here}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, instead of loading all above html code inside my modal, I just want to display divs #myContent1 and #myContent2.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery ajax functions:

```
$( "#myContent1" ).load( "ajax/test1.html" );
$( "#myContent2" ).load( "ajax/test2.html" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using page fragments you can load specific divs to specific divs.
For example

> `$('#mainContainer').load('loadpage.html #nav1div');`

Will load stuff inside your mainContainer that appear inside the div nav1div from the loaded page ('loadpage.html'), for more info check out http://api.jquery.com/load/